# How to get the name of the collection an item is bound to?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Apologies for not posting any code for this but all my efforts seem to be going nowhere.

I need to get the name of an observableCollection a textblock is bound to from the mouseDown event handler, so I can then perform some operations on the data,  is there any way to do this?

I have set the Tag of the textblock to {binding} so i get the entire object back the textblock is bound to. Other than this im not sure where to go next.

Update:

The reason for this is that I have 2 multiselect treeviews, with a heirarchial data template, each template shares the same treeview but is bound to a different observable collection.

The way my multiselect works is by applying a style to each treeview if the IsSelected value of that item in my collection is true.

Now I am using the Mousedown event handler for the textblock in my datatemplate to get the item I am working on, BUT some items can be in both collections at once. I need to know which item to set the IsSelected value on.  Using Binding{tag} I get the Item I need to set on but not the collection it is within.

I'm using Mousedown as the event handler because If you click on one item to select it, then click again it needs to unselect and the treeview event handlers didnt seem to allow this to happen (SelectedItemChanged etc).

As a side note I also need to be able to hide the default selected style of the Treeview as this isnt used and it gets confusing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'name' of the observableCollection?

Comment: The name of the variable,  I have one collection named Available and one named Selected, I just need some way of identifying which one of these collections I am selecting items in.

Comment: Variable names are not available at runtime. If you post your actual goal maybe we can help you find another way to acheive it.

Comment: @Gabe Thanks, Im probably going about this the wrong way, been working on the problem too long lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't determine what collection an item is in, but you can determine what TreeView the user clicked on. Then you can get the collection by knowing the TreeView, which should solve your immediate problem.

Comment: I tried this, the problem here is that the GotFocus event for the treeview fires after the MouseDown event for the Textblock in the Hierarchial Data Template :( is there a way other than GotFocus I can do this?

Comment: @Purplegoldfish: You don't need the `GotFocus` event. Once you have the `TextBlock` you can follow its `Parent` property upwards (you may need to use `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent`) until you get to one or the other `TreeView`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at that and see where I get